# How to access state of one component into another component in react

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class one extends React.Component 
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = {
            number:26
        }
    }
    render()
    {
        return(
            <div></div>
        );
    }
}
export default one;

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import one from './one'
class HomePage extends React.Component 
{
    render()
    {
        return(
            <div>{one.state.number}</div>
        );
    }
}
export default HomePage;
```

**is it possible to access number state**
is there any way to access state of one component into another component?
please suggest me if any solution is present.

Comment: No you can't access state of one component in another. State is private to a React class. What you can do though, is lift the state up to the component in which you want to use it and pass it as prop to the child if there is a direct relationship else you may need to store it in a global store such as redux store

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [Shubam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928186/shubham-khatri) has explained it, Though I would like to form it as a complete answer

First of all, I would like to let you know that Never Use lowercase letters to name your React Components.So name your component to `One` instead of `one`.

Now Comming back to your question:-
 **No This is not Possible**, If your app contains few components then it's better to pass the `state` object as the `props`, But if your app contains too many components then better to use predictable state containers like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) or [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) rather than passing state as props.

So you may apply these changes and I hope You will get What You Desire:-

**One Component**:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Homepage from './homepage';

class One extends React.Component 
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state = {
            number:26
        }
    }
    render()
    {
        return(
            <Homepage data={this.state}/>
        );
    }
}

export default One;
```

**Homepage Component**:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Homepage extends React.Component 
{

    render()
    {
        console.log("this is homepage",this.props);
        return(
            <div>{this.props.data.number}</div>
        );
    }
}

export default Homepage;
```

Please Raise Your doubts if any, Or if you find any error in it.

Comment: Thanks, Vinit raj, But here I am calling One component in HomePage. As you wrote above, in this case, first I have to call One but my main page is homePage component So it must for me to call HomePage component first instead of all other components

Comment: The only reason you called one component in Homepage component is to access its state right?? But that is not the right way i just followed the way so that it can be easier for me to pass state as props as it is the only way here rather than using redux or flux

Comment: Actually what I am doing here, One is a component having 5 states and also have 4-5 methods so here it changes it states values using its own method ( using onClick, onChange ) based on the value of this One component I am rendering some other components in Homepage that why I am doing this.

Comment: Can you tell me where u r rendering homepage component??

Comment: Even You have lots of method in one component, The only way you can access one's state is to pass it as props, So wherever you are rendering Homepage component just make sure you pass some props which contain one's state as simple as that.

Comment: suppose i have 3 component in one jsx  file  so how could i access the value of state from one component to another